# Error on Github deploy on windows azure

Tags: windows, node.js, deployment, azure, github

hej,
since march we got some troubles with our deployments on our windows azure server.
It seems that the deployments doesn't work and because sometimes it works sometimes not i don't get it.

Some kind of error i saw on my windows azure dashboard -> deployments:

"Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)."

or

"Host key verification failed. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

i tried to restart the server or make new commits to github or simply redeploy or disconnect and reconnect to github. At the moment nothing works. There is a development server and a live server. Both contains the exact similiar version of the website (written in node.js). i've checked it a lot of times. Deployment with the development version works fine. live dont.

Do you have any suggestions? I have no idea where to start :-(

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web role you can check the iisnode/ folder, should contain the log files. They can also be accessed with the emulator running, try

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/iisnode/
```